# How to count unique words in a string using RegEx and just re.findall() function?

Tags: python, regex, punctuation

I'm new to RE and I'm trying to figure out how to return a count of all unique words in a string given an inputted string. The problem I keep running into is punctuation. I don't want my code to treat words like "dog" and "dog," separately. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `\w+` in your regular expression to only match letters, digits and underscore. Use `set` to exclude duplicates:

```
len(set(re.findall(r'\w+', text, re.UNICODE)))
```